# Packaging projects or maps without data source connections in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, map-package

I have 4 map layers that each have the exact same data sources/layers but the colours are different (four different basemap designs).

I want to package the project or map layers to share it without copying the geodatabase where the data sources are connected to as it is quite large at ~10 GB. The recipient of the packaged file will connect to their own FGDB that has the same layers just covering a different area.

Is this possible? I have looked into arcpy package project and package map but no luck.

Comment: I'd zip project folder without gdb. Tell client to copy their version manually. Same name of course

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is sort of an anti-pattern in packaging and sharing: Share something that when given to someone else will have broken data links. The entire point of packaging is to create a package that is usable by the recipient.

From the documentation of the [Package Project tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/tool-reference/data-management/package-project.htm), you can achieve what you want if you setup your map in a certain way. See the **Share outside of organization** parameter. If you build your maps up with data from either an eGDB or referenced from a `\\server\unc\path`, you can choose to **not** include the data in the package. This package should work just fine for someone within your organization, but will obviously be broken outside your organization (they'll need to fix data paths). I'd guess you're referencing data locally right now (`c:\mydata\stuff.gdb`). You'll need to update paths to `\\unc\data` and then build your package as explained.

The other alternative would be to create **layer files**. You can generate and share these. These are essentially directions on how to draw the layer and can be passed around without the data. The recipient would then use them to style the data. You can read more about the [Apply Symbology from Layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm) tool here.